# How to limited EditText for start characters just english alphabet in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I want use `EditText` and I want **start** characters **just English alphabet**.
My mean is, **First** of characters has just **English alphabet** (a to z).

**I write below codes :**

```
registerUsernameEdtTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (charSequence.toString().length() < 2) {
            registerUsernameEdtTxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                           int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                    if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                        registerUsernameInptLay.setErrorEnabled(false);
                        return src;
                    }
                    registerUsernameInptLay.setError(context.getResources().getString(R.string.insertJustEnglish));
                    return "";
                }
            }});
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

But not work me! How can I it?

Please help me

Comment: What error or improper output are you getting?

Comment: @TomAranda, not error. but not work. can you test my code  and see it? please

Comment: What is the is the desired output and what output are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.text_field);

// This part is to keep the existing filters of the EditText.
InputFilter[] filters = et.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = Arrays.copyOf(filters, filters.length + 1);

InputFilter firstFilter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (source != null && source.length() > 0 && dstart == 0){
            if (!source.toString().matches("^[A-Za-z].*"))
                return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
};

// Add the filter to the array of filters
newFilters[newFilters.length - 1] = firstFilter;

et.setFilters(newFilters);
```

Can be simplified like this (if the previous InputFilter are not required)

```
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.text_field);
InputFilter firstFilter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (source != null && source.length() > 0 && dstart == 0){
            if (!source.toString().matches("^[A-Za-z].*"))
                return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
};
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{firstFilter});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the rest of the string (for example if the user pastes the text):

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    if (source != null && source.length() > 0 && dstart == 0) {
        String s = source.toString();
        if (!s.matches("^[A-Za-z].*")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return s.substring(1, s.length());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The above versions don't work on deletion or when a text is pasted with more than a forbidden char at the beginning (e.g. '88sdfs') as only the first one was removed and the rest kept.
This new version should cover all these cases.

I'd suggest to create a separated class for the InputFilter.

```
InputFilter firstFilter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (dstart != 0) { // The modified part is not beginning of the text
            return null; // Nothing need to be changed
        }
        if (source.length() > 0) { // text is added
            return onTextAdded(source.toString());
        } else { // text is removed
            return onTextRemoved(dest, dend);
        }
    }

    private CharSequence onTextRemoved(Spanned dest, int dend) {
        // check what the string will look like after the text being removed
        String substring = dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());
        // if there is still a string and it's not valid
        if (substring.length() > 0 && !isValid(substring)) {
            displayError();
            // return the deleted part for the string to not change
            return dest.subSequence(0, dend);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String onTextAdded(String s) {
        if (isValid(s)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String substring;
            // We want to keep a part of the added string (it can be a paste).
            // so we remove all the first characters as long as the string doesn't match
            // the requirements
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
                substring = s.substring(i, s.length());
                if (isValid(substring))
                    break;
            }
            displayError();
            return substring;
        }
    }

    private boolean isValid(String s) {
        return s.matches("^[A-Za-z].*");
    }

    private void displayError() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{firstFilter});
```

Comment: thanks my friend, but I want set this filter just first character!

Comment: please help me my bro

Comment: I want show toast error when start other characters! how can I show this error with your code my bro?

Comment: Just add your Toast before `return ""`

Comment: There was some issues, I've updated the answer. Should be fixed now. Unfortunately it has became bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your project:

```
public class EnglishInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int dstart, int dend) {

        StringBuilder newChars = new StringBuilder(charSequence.toString().substring(start, end));

        for (int i = 0; i < newChars.length(); ) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(newChars.charAt(i)))
                newChars.deleteCharAt(i);
            else
                i++;
        }
        return newChars.toString();
    }

}
```

Then do this with your EditText:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new EnglishInputFilter()});
```

It also removes no letter characters from pasted strings, if you paste "1A2B" it will really paste "AB"

You can add more filters, for example for limit the total length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your edit text should accept starting first character with any English alphabet Then you can use regular expression like;

```
    String regexp = "^([a-zA-Z]+).*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    boolean ismatches = pattern.matcher("your input that start with the alphabet").matches();


if(ismatches)
     do your stuff
else
     show error
```